# Need to select corresponding Maximum values from the list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a continues list like `[('0', 0.9999883), ('1', 0.00092986226), ('2', 0.00052163005), ('3', 0.00080531836)]` this, need to select the max value corresponding number ... how can we iterate ?

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Do you just want `'0'` as your output?

Comment: You can iterate a list in python with: `for item in myList:`. In `item[0]` you will have '0', '1' etc, and in `item[1]` you will have the v alue.btw: "('0', 0.9999883)" in `python` is called a `tuple`, not a `list`.

Comment: My output should be "0" or "1" or '2' or '3' based on Max value on the list ..

Answer (score 1):

Do a simple linear search for the maximum:

```
my_list = [('0', 0.9999883), ('1', 0.00092986226), ('2', 0.00052163005), ('3', 0.00080531836)]
max_value = 0
max_index = 0
for e in my_list:
    if e[1] > max_value:
        max_value = e[1]
        max_index = e[0]
print(max_index) #0
print(max_value) #0.9999883
```

Comment: Every `e` object in `my_list` is a tuple, not a value.

Comment: @Aryerez Yup, therefore I am looking at `e[0]` and `e[1]` (the stored indices and values of each tuple), as opposed to looking at just `e`.

Comment: Good to know that there is a way to edit your answer without being showed it was edited...

Comment: Quick edits (in the first 2 or 3 mins) do not get reflected.

Comment: Ok. But I believe that if someone gave a right comment, the responder, that changed his answer, should be honest enough not to make it seems like the comment is wrong and doesn't understand what is written, and could have write something like "I fixed / edited it" instead.

Comment: Agreed. Your comment arrived 6 minutes after my answer, hence I naturally assumed that your comment was about the version you saw at that moment, which is 5 minutes after my edit. Hence there was no way for me to know that you meant the first version. So yes, I did edit my answer.

Comment: bro i have value like [('2', 3.9726496e-05), ('3', 7.119775e-05)] expo values too and continous of lists like above i mentioned . when i go for max it picks expo because it start with 3. or 7. when it compare to others

Comment: @maniDILLS Your question is getting convoluted. Please give me a clear, full list that has those scientific values and your desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this:

```
>>> lst = [('0', 0.9999883), ('1', 0.00092986226), ('2', 0.00052163005), ('3', 0.00080531836)]
>>> max(lst,key=lambda x:x[1])
('0', 0.9999883)
```

If you want only the string part you can do:

```
>>> max(lst,key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
'0'
```

You have put the lists in literals, so if they are in string you want something like this:

```
>>> lst = "[('0', 0.0015696287), ('1', 0.0053164363), ('2', 0.0008648634), ('3', 0.999303)]", "[('0', 0.00064742565), ('1', 0.030319422), ('2', 0.9896703), ('3', 0.004443854)]", "[('0', 0.99982405), ('1', 0.00092729926), ('2', 0.001509279), ('3', 0.00065752864)]", "[('0', 0.0030318499), ('1', 0.01600933), ('2', 0.9892292), ('3', 0.028750658)]", "[('0', 0.9989308), ('1', 0.0029929578), ('2', 0.0014030635), ('3', 0.0016490221)]", "[('0', 0.0027604103), ('1', 0.009357661), ('2', 0.0014455616), ('3', 0.99934363)]"

>>> [max(eval(inner_lst),key=lambda x:x[1]) for inner_lst in lst]
[('3', 0.999303), ('2', 0.9896703), ('0', 0.99982405), ('2', 0.9892292), ('0', 0.9989308), ('3', 0.99934363)]
```

Or if you like:

```
>>> [max(eval(inner_lst),key=lambda x:x[1])[0] for inner_lst in lst]
['3', '2', '0', '2', '0', '3']
```

If they are not in strings, and they are just in a list:

```
>>> lst = [[('0', 0.0015696287), ('1', 0.0053164363), ('2', 0.0008648634), ('3', 0.999303)], [('0', 0.00064742565), ('1', 0.030319422), ('2', 0.9896703), ('3', 0.004443854)], [('0', 0.99982405), ('1', 0.00092729926), ('2', 0.001509279), ('3', 0.00065752864)], [('0', 0.0030318499), ('1', 0.01600933), ('2', 0.9892292), ('3', 0.028750658)], [('0', 0.9989308), ('1', 0.0029929578), ('2', 0.0014030635), ('3', 0.0016490221)], [('0', 0.0027604103), ('1', 0.009357661), ('2', 0.0014455616), ('3', 0.99934363)]]
>>> print([max(inner_lst,key=lambda x:x[1])[0] for inner_lst in lst])
['3', '2', '0', '2', '0', '3']
```

Comment: bro i have value like [('2', 3.9726496e-05), ('3', 7.119775e-05)] expo values it should me min then 0 correct ??.... but while going for max its comes first

Comment: Do you want to calculate the `max` and `min` based on the first index? If so your `key` would be `key = lambda x:int(x[0])`. I am sorry, I need a little clearer explanation here.

Comment: ,
 "[('0', 0.0015696287), ('1', 0.0053164363), ('2', 0.0008648634), ('3', 0.999303)]",
 "[('0', 0.00064742565), ('1', 0.030319422), ('2', 0.9896703), ('3', 0.004443854)]",
 "[('0', 0.99982405), ('1', 0.00092729926), ('2', 0.001509279), ('3', 0.00065752864)]",
 "[('0', 0.0030318499), ('1', 0.01600933), ('2', 0.9892292), ('3', 0.028750658)]",
 "[('0', 0.9989308), ('1', 0.0029929578), ('2', 0.0014030635), ('3', 0.0016490221)]",
 "[('0', 0.0027604103), ('1', 0.009357661), ('2', 0.0014455616), ('3', 0.99934363)]",
 i have continues list from each list i want max numbers corresponding value .

Comment: You have put the lists in double quotes, does that mean you have the lists in strings?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the maximum tuple using the second value:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = [('0', 0.9999883), ('1', 0.00092986226), ('2', 0.00052163005), ('3', 0.00080531836)]
>>> max(l, key=itemgetter(1))
('0', 0.9999883)
```

If you just want the first item returned:

```
>>> max(l, key=itemgetter(1))[0]
'0'
```

The above uses [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to select the second item as the the max `key`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> your_list = [('0', 0.9999883), ('1', 0.00092986226), ('2', 0.00052163005), ('3', 0.00080531836)]
>>> max(your_list , key= lambda x: x[1])
('0', 0.9999883) # output
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick for you:

```
a = [('0', 0.9999883), ('1', 0.00092986226), ('2', 0.00052163005), ('3', 0.00080531836)]

tmp0, tmp1 = a[0][0], a[0][1]

for i,j in a:
    if tmp1 < j:
        tmp0 = i
        tmp1 = j

print(tmp0, tmp1)
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it solves the problem. "ahhh" is not a valid description...